# Asynchronous C# StartInfo process dumps stdout lines, only if stderr is not redirected?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, io-redirection

I'm working on a C# application where there a process is ran, and the output lines are output in real-time (asynchronously) as per [c# run CL exe or batch cpture output LIVE to textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778924/c-sharp-run-cl-exe-or-batch-cpture-output-live-to-textbox) , with a code like this:

```csharp
    Process new_process = new Process();

    new_process.StartInfo.FileName = tool_exe;
    new_process.StartInfo.Arguments = tool_arguments;
    new_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    new_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    //new_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    new_process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    new_process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    string line;
    
    void _cmd_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        line = e.Data;
        MyAppendTextBox1(line);
    }
    void _cmd_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyAppendTextBox1("err: " + e.Data);
    }
    bool did_start = new_process.Start();
    if (did_start)
    {
        new_process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(_cmd_OutputDataReceived);
        new_process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(_cmd_ErrorDataReceived);
        //new_process.Exited += new EventHandler(_cmd_Exited);
        new_process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        new_process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }

    new_process.WaitForExit();
```

Now, the thing is, it seems that the `tool_exe` might do something weird itself with stderr and stdout redirections ... so what I observe is this:

- If RedirectStandardError is not true (line commented) - then upon run, I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: StandardError has not been redirected.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.BeginErrorReadLine()
```

... but otherwise, code works perfectly, text box is updated in realtime, process exits succesfully.

- But, if I try to remedy that exception by uncommenting the line, and setting new_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true - then, when the program is ran, only a single line is printed (_cmd_OutputDataReceived triggers only once), and then the C# program appears to freeze, and process does not seem to exit (so I have to shutdown everything from Windows Task Manager) ?!

I cannot imagine why would this behavior happen at all (how come it works only when I get an exception)?!

The only thing I've noticed is that the above code runs in a context of a click handler; and when running a build with RedirectStandardError = true, then when it freezes, I actually see some messages that I otherwise expected in the output, show up in the Debug output window of VS2019 (possibly after the debuggee is shut down)?

Would anyone have an idea what is going on here, and how can I get proper operation without exception?

Comment: Have you tried attaching handlers on the `OutputDataReceived` etc events *before* starting the `Process`?

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias - just tried that, and it does not make a difference; also, strangely, if `RedirectStandardError = true;` is commented, and I also comment `new_process.BeginErrorReadLine();` to avoid exception, then *again* I get a freeze?!

Comment: When does `new_process` exit? If the answer is "never", then, yeah, you'll freeze forever on the `WaitForExit()`. If you call `BeginErrorReadLine()` without setting `RedirectStandardError` to true, then you'll get an exception, but that exception happens after you've begin reading standard output, hence why it "works" (but execution never reaches `WaitForExit()`, so no "freeze"). Presumably, you're catching the exception somewhere, otherwise you'd crash.

Comment: Thanks @EtiennedeMartel - in general, `new_process` exits after anywhere between 10 seconds and a minute - however, when in debugger and experiencing the above problem, it seemed that it just kept on hanging (since I was not seeing any output from it in the C# application, as I noted). However, I experimented a bit more, and got both stderr and stdout to print without exception as noted in my answer below

Comment: Could you include in the question the `MyAppendTextBox1` method? Also please specify where the whole code is located (the code that creates the `new_process`). Is it located in the event handler of a UI control?

Answer (score 0):

It seems by reorganizing the code this way, I could get it run with both stdout and stderr redirected properly without exception (but with the below changes, WaitForExit() does not work anymore:

```csharp
    Process new_process = new Process();

    new_process.StartInfo.FileName = tool_exe;
    new_process.StartInfo.Arguments = tool_arguments;
    new_process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // https://stackoverflow.com/q/4504170
    new_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    new_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    new_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    new_process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    new_process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    string line;
    
    void _cmd_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        line = e.Data;
        MyAppendTextBox1(line);
    }
    void _cmd_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyAppendTextBox1("err: " + e.Data);
    }
    void _cmd_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new_process.OutputDataReceived -= new DataReceivedEventHandler(_cmd_OutputDataReceived);
        new_process.ErrorDataReceived -= new DataReceivedEventHandler(_cmd_ErrorDataReceived);
        new_process.Exited -= new EventHandler(_cmd_Exited);
    }

    new_process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(_cmd_OutputDataReceived);
    new_process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(_cmd_ErrorDataReceived);
    new_process.Exited += new EventHandler(_cmd_Exited);

    new_process.Start();
    new_process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    new_process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```