# Redirect but also display process output stream

Tags: c#, redirect, process, stdout

I am running a build, and I would like to be able to view the progress as it happens.  But I would also like to save the output if the build has an error.

I know I can use `Process.UseShellExecute = false`, and `RedirectStandardOutput`, but that's only part of the story.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

As Greg mentions in the comments below, MSBuild can write out to a log file while also outputting to console out of the box.

```
MSBuild [options] /filelogger /fileloggerparameters:LogFile=MSBuildLog.txt
```

---

Try the following simple C# program. It will take the redirected STDIN (`Console.In`) and write it to one or more files and STDOUT (`Console.Out`).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace RedirectToFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var buffer = new char[100];
            var outputs = new List<TextWriter>();

            foreach (var file in args)
                outputs.Add(new StreamWriter(file));

            outputs.Add(Console.Out);

            int bytesRead;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = Console.In.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                outputs.ForEach(o => o.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            } while (bytesRead == buffer.Length);

            outputs.ForEach(o => o.Close());
        }
    }
}
```

I use it to redirect the output from an MSBuild batch file to disk *whilst* still outputting to the console window.

```
Usage: MSBuild [options] | RedirectToFile.exe MSBuildLog.txt
```

Comment: `ReadBlock()` isn't required to always return the whole buffer full. You should check for `bytesRead > 0` instead.

Comment: +1 this works pretty well, (despite it being somewhat spastic about how it prints to the screen) but unfortunately the colors from msbuild are lost.  Any idea how to preserve those?

Comment: Using the above program, there is no way to preserve the console output colours. If want additional logging from MSBuild have a look at the `msbuild.exe /logger` option, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx

Comment: MSBuild can write out to a log file while also outputting to console out of the box. `MSBuild [options] /filelogger /fileloggerparameters:LogFile=MSBuildLog.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this?

```
class Tee
{
    private readonly string m_programPath;
    private readonly string m_logPath;
    private TextWriter m_writer;

    public Tee(string programPath, string logPath)
    {
        m_programPath = programPath;
        m_logPath = logPath;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        using (m_writer = new StreamWriter(m_logPath))
        {

            var process =
                new Process
                {
                    StartInfo =
                        new ProcessStartInfo(m_programPath)
                        { RedirectStandardOutput = true, UseShellExecute = false }
                };

            process.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

    private void OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        m_writer.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1.  I'm sure this works, but I had trouble getting it to work, probably because I'm using a static class.

Answer (score 1):

this answer should help you [Redirect Standard Output Efficiently in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164736/redirect-standard-output-efficiently-in-net)

PS I am never sure if linking to another answer on SO is an answer or a comment

Comment: good link but it doesn't quite show what I was looking for exactly.