# command prompt c#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirect Standard Output Efficiently in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164736/redirect-standard-output-efficiently-in-net)
>   [Capturing console output from a .NET application (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c)

I know how to execute something like this:

```
SomeEXE inputfile.txt
```

in the command prompt via C#.

The problem I am having is that SomeEXE opens another command prompt where it writes the outputs given inputfile.txt.

Is it generally possible to obtain these outputs? Thanks.

Here is my current code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C SomeEXE inputfile.txt";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

// Now use streams to capture the output
StreamReader outputReader = process.StandardOutput;

process.WaitForExit();

String line = outputReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=console+redirect

Comment: @Dan-o more like http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=console+redirect+%5Bc%23%5D&submit=search

Comment: @wraith808: that will work too :)

Comment: @Steve B I am not doing anything wrong. I just wonder whether it is possible.

Comment: @Alex K. I am aware of this and the comment does not help at all.

Comment: Then stating why that standard redirection approach fails in your scenario would be helpful

Comment: The question states that it opens another command prompt.

Comment: I really do not understand why you close this. I am aware of the other stuff. The problem is that the command, after being issued from C#, opens another command prompt. This command prompt contains all the output! I believe I stated this clearly: SomeEXE opens another command prompt

Comment: I have rewritten my original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373515/command-issued-via-c-sharp-opens-another-command-prompt

Answer (score 1):

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new processStartInfo("SomeEXE", "inputfile.txt");
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

// Here is where you grab the output:
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Process process = new Process {
  StartInfo = processStartInfo
};
process.Start();

// Now use streams to capture the output
StreamReader outputReader = process.StandardOutput;

process.WaitForExit();
```

Now you can read the `outputStream` as necessary.

*I am guessing this is what you mean. Also, here are the docs on [`RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)*

Also, if you know the path to the file that was generated (assuming the `SomeEXE` wrote to another file) you can use [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.open.aspx) to access its contents after `SomeEXE` has executed (remember to wait until after otherwise `SomeEXE` may still have a handle on the file making it difficult to read it).

Comment: This does not work as the command opens another command prompt where it also writes the output (no output file). Furthermore the other command prompt wait for input (carriage return).

Comment: So the first app (launched by `Process`) launches another window executing another application which is the output you _really_ want?

Comment: Exactly. I thought I made that clear in my original question - sorry if not (-: