# command issued via C# opens another command prompt

Tags: c#, .net

I am using code like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C SomeEXE inputfile.txt";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

// Now use streams to capture the output
StreamReader outputReader = process.StandardOutput;

process.WaitForExit();

String line = outputReader.ReadToEnd();
```

This works fine. However, the issued command (SomeEXE) results in another command prompt being opened which contains the actual results and awaits a carriage return to be closed. Is it possible to obtain this output and issue a carriage return? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Launching SomeEXE directly**

If you launch SomeEXE directly, rather than via a new command interpreter, your existing code to obtain the output by redirecting stdout to *outputReader* will work.  To do that, change your code as follows:

```
startInfo.FileName = "SomeEXE";
startInfo.Arguments = "inputfile.txt";
```

You can redirect stdin to your own stream as well so that you can issue the carriage return:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx

Key points:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;
```

Write Environment.NewLine to myStreamWriter.

However, since you are not doing that, you are capturing the console of the command interpreter.

**If you control SomeEXE's code**

If you have control over SomeEXE, you can instruct it to attach to its parent's console:

http://www.csharp411.com/console-output-from-winforms-application/

Note that the MSDN examples show very poor exception handling.  They fail to close the streams in the example if an exception is thrown.  The easiest way to dispose of the streams is to wrap them in *using* statements.

**If SomeEXE spawns a child process**

If you have no control over SomeEXE's code, and SomeEXE is spawning a child process, the task of grabbing stdin/stdout from the grandchild console is harder.  However, it can be done.

You need to [obtain the process ID](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/get-a-list-of-running-processes-in-c/) of the actual console window in question.

Then, you can use the Win32 API [AttachConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952.aspx) to attach the grandchild process' console to your own.

Comment: I do not obtain the output - at least the string is empty. The 'spawned off command prompt' contains the output data. The question is how do I get these data.

Comment: Oh I see.  Give me a moment to consider that.

Comment: FYI... why are you launching SomeEXE via a new command shell rather than directly as the target of process.Start()?

Comment: Updated my answer, though I don't fully know your situation yet.

Comment: Basically I can manually run: SomeEXE inputfile.txt in the command prompt. This spawns off another command prompt window which contains the output and waits for the user to press enter. This created by SomeEXE and not by me. I would like to get hold of this output and issue SomeEXE programmatically. Does this make sense?

Comment: Can you please clarify: FYI... why are you launching SomeEXE via a new command shell rather than directly as the target of process.Start()? Also, no I do not have control over SomeEXE. It is a 3rd party application.

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify that point.  However if SomeEXE itself is launching a new window, the task is more difficult.  Added thoughts on that as well.