# How to capture output from a cmd line process running in the background of C# WPF app?

Tags: c#, redirect, command-line, output

I've seen a ton of articles on Stack Overflow (and the rest of the Internet) for starting a command-line process in the background of a C# application, however all of the examples put a `process.WaitForExit()` command at the end.

My issue is that I need to keep the process alive in the background so that my WPF app can communicate with it (client/server style).  My code successfully runs the process and my app can communicate with it, but I can't seem to capture any of the output.

Simplified code.

In `App.xaml.cs`:

```
private Process hostApplication;
private FileInfo hostApplicationFilename;
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // Start the command line process
    hostApplication = new Process();
    hostApplicationFilename = new FileInfo(@"C:\pretendpath\myEXE.exe");

    hostApplication.StartInfo.FileName = hostApplicationFilename.FullName;
    hostApplication.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = hostApplicationFilename.DirectoryName;

    hostApplication.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    hostApplication.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    hostApplication.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    hostApplication.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    hostApplication.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    hostApplication.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    hostApplication.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(HostApplicationOutputHandler);
    hostApplication.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(HostApplicationOutputHandler);
    hostApplication.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    hostApplication.Start();
    hostApplication.BeginOutputReadLine();
    hostApplication.BeginErrorReadLine();

    // Start the WPF's main window
    MainWindow view = new MainWindow();
    view.Show();
}

private void HostApplicationOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
    {
        LocalHostApplicationLog = Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data;
#if (DEBUG)
        Console.WriteLine("HOST APPLICATION OUTPUT: " + outLine.Data);
#endif
    }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the `DataReceivedEventHandler`, it's never hit.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should perhaps create a new thread, start your client process in that thread, and waitforexit in that thread.

Comment: I have now tried that.  I put all of the above code related to `hostApplication` in its own thread and added a `hostApplication.WaitForExit()` at the end.  What happens now is that the breakpoint in the DataReceivedEventHandler gets hit once I close the MainWindow.  Once the MainWindow is closed, all of the process's output gets dumped at once.

Comment: It may be that the client process is buffering the output stream - is it something you have control over? If you do, can you flush the output stream every time you write to it?

Comment: If you do not have any control over the client process, another way to redirect the output/error streams is as shown in [another post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164736/redirect-standard-output-efficiently-in-net)

Comment: The method used in the post you linked to worked until I tried to also redirect input.

Comment: I do have some control over the process, and flushing the stream works. Now I just have to convince the owner of that software to include the flushing.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of help.